# Nginx TLS redirect based on IP address

Tags: linux, nginx

Is it possible to  configire nginx to use TLS1.2 version for certain IP's and TLS1.0 for  user defined IP's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just let one `server` block listen to the first set of ips (and configure that block using TLSv1.2), and let another `server` block listen with other IP addresses. In the latter block you'd only configure TLSv1.0

An example would be

```
server {
    listen                 1.1.1.1:443 ssl;
    server_name     tls1_0.example.com;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers     "_cleared_for_brevity_";
    ssl_dhparam     /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;

    // ..other config

    tcp_nodelay     on;
}

server {
    listen                 1.1.1.2:443 ssl;
    server_name     tls1_2.example.com;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers     "_cleared_for_brevity_";
    ssl_dhparam     /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;

    // ..other config

    tcp_nodelay     on;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Can we configure different networks instead of a particular IP Address.